# android define values in resource xml files

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay

I tried to define values in `dimens.xml` as

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_action_bar_overlay_margin">?attr/actionBarSize</dimen>

</resources>
```

and use `activity_action_bar_overlay_margin` as

```
<!-- activity_main.xml in layout folder, this is the main activity-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_action_bar_overlay_margin" >

<!-- activity_display_message.xml in layout folder, this is sub-activity -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

and the app crashed when run it. Now if I use:

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

as stated in

[Specify Layout Top-margin](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

The code partially works, as `display_message_activity` (I added a `Up` button in it, `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`) could not show the message passed from `main_activity`, with or without specifying

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

So I have two questions:

1. How do I specify values like `?attr/actionBarSize` (I don't know what kinda value is it) in resource `xml` files.
2. How to show the messages passed to `display_message_activity`? I don't know if it is the action bar that covered the `textView` that displays the message.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

if  you want use actionBar attrs,must android 3.0 or later .
'?attr/actionBarSize'  from  android  source framework resources;
path:framework/base/core/res/res/values/styles .
ref doc link :[android action bar](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

Comment: From the last paragraph of http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html, `?attr/actionBarSize` value without the prefix works on all versions, including Android 3.0 and higher.